# Trouble Show output using hadoop word count

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, word-count

I'm new to using Hadoop, and I want to execute Hadoop syntax using WordCount to count words. However, why is it that when I try to display the output, it doesn't appear? I would appreciate an explanation and assistance[image]

yarn-site.xml settings:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml settings:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

note : i'm use hadoop version 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

1. You have an error there - `/tmp` is not a valid Windows path, and your `/tmp/hadoop-<username>` value is not a valid Shell command. You need to override `hadoop.tmp.dir` in `core-site.xml` to a valid Windows path like `file://c:/tmp_hadoop`
2. I'd suggest using WSL2, not CMD. Hadoop is not really designed to run on Windows.
3. The execution of Mapreduce runs outside of your terminal session, in multiple YARN containers. There is a driver (your terminal) and executors (where job output is stored).

   You can open link in your logs - `The url to track the job` or `For more detailed output...` to find the real issue

---

If you want WordCount in less code, with faster output, and more interactive session, then use Spark. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#more-on-dataset-operations

Comment: Do I need to create the 'tmp' folder in Hadoop, or does Hadoop create it automatically?

Comment: Should I set additional configurations in the core site like this, And should I create a 'tmp' folder?:
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
 <value>C:\hadoop\tmp</value>
</property>

Comment: I've not ran hadoop on windows to be able to answer that, but go ahead and try. As suggested, use WSL2 if you want hadoop to just work with a default assumption of a Linux filesystem. Reminder that Spark doesn't require HDFS or YARN