# issue running hadoop mapreduce wordcount

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, word-count

I am running Hadoop version 3.2.4 in windows and want to perform a WordCount operation on the file located in `hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/share/mapreduce-examples-3.2.4.jar`. However, it failed, and there is an error message as follows:

```
Application application_1699601027477_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1699601027477_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
    Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-11-10 14:44:16.479]Exception from container-launch.
    Container id: container_1699601027477_0002_02_000001
    Exit code: 1
    Exception message: '/tmp/hadoop-ryan' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    [2023-11-10 14:44:16.479]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
    [2023-11-10 14:44:16.479]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
    For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://LAPTOP-IPDKGW12:8088/cluster/app/application_1699601027477_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
    . Failing the application.
```

this is my settings :

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I appreciate it if anyone can provide input or advice regarding any mistakes I may have made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble Show output using hadoop word count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440227/trouble-show-output-using-hadoop-word-count)

Comment: You are getting the exact same error. Please don't repost

Comment: i still have same error

Comment: The core-site you've posted doesn't have hadoop.tmp.dir as suggested? Have you tried using WSL2? Hadoop just doesn't run very well in Windows, so using a Linux environment would work much better

Comment: i have change add hadoop.tmp.dir too but still error

Comment: Okay, and WSL2 has the same problem or not? That setting worked for this user on an Ubuntu machine https://stackoverflow.com/a/77467484/2308683